# How should I build pantheon to max damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

I basically want to get as much damage as possible, nearly as close to 500 AD. So far I've gone up to 445 AD at most and regularly I get to around 350 AD. So how do I get max damage on panth.

Comment: Max AD is not always Max Damage. and both is not recommend for a serious game.

Comment: Max dmg you should probably build Black cleaver, Last whisper and 4x Bloodthirster. Now is this a viable build in a real game? Probably not but it should get close to max dmg output.

Comment: why 4 bloodthirster?! fully stacked sword of occult give 110AD

Comment: "max damage" in this case is a completely arbitrary term. Max damage against what? An enemy with 20 armor and 5,000hp? An enemy with 300 armor & 1,000hp? An enemy which you can only poke with abilities? Or an enemy which you can constantly stay on their face and auto attack as well, with no gap closing/kiting problems? Do you have any gold constraints? Are you after the highest damage in an individual hit, or highest damage over a period of time? In any case, whilst high AD certainly help towards "max damage", it's not the only contributing factor.

Comment: It's really depending on situation, if they are building a lot of armor, then you might deal more damage with armor pen. instead of brute forcing with AD. Anyway max dmg on pantheon isn't a really recommended build since his late game has very little dmg whatever build path you take and you'll rather be peeling for your adc than to be like fiora.

Answer (score 1):

### Max AD is not always Max Damage.

**and both is not recommend for a serious game.**

However:

**Max AD:**

Full AD Runepage

Offensive Masteries

Items:

- Sword of the Occult (fully stacked 110 AD)
- Maw of Malmortius (when below 65% health 95 AD)
- 4x Infinity Edge/Bloodthirster/Mercurial Scimitar/Essence Reaver (each 80 AD)

**Max Damage/DPS (almost viable....):**

[image: Runepage]:

[image: Offensive Masteries]

Items:

- Hydra
- Last Whipser
- Black Cleaver
- Bloodthirster
- Ionian Boots of Lucidity
- Maw of Malmortius

Pantheon is an AD Caster and benefits alot from ArmorPenetration. I acutally use this runepage and those masteries. I play a lot of pantheon lately. You should definitly build tanky after Hydra and Black Cleaver and go for NinjaTabis or MercTreads. Since you somehow fall off in the late game you try to peel, zone and lower everyones armor.

Comment: Have never really used occult (for semi obvious reasons), does it work with multiple? Like just building 6 occults and stacking them full?

Comment: no. unique passive.

Comment: Can you edit in how much AD you gain from runes/masteries and the total AD amount for the Max AD case? I think this information would improve your answer. Might also be useful to do similar for the DPS build.

Also, I don't think your match history helps this answer; but if you are intent on keeping it, I recommend censoring out the summoner names

Comment: @Bob2Chiv I was planing to do so, but haven't had the time yet.